# I am trying to check and see if some files exist. Why won't my program let the user enter a file?

Tags: java, file-io, input, logic, runtime-error

The code compiles, however after prompting the user for a file name it immediately says invalid input (which is what it should say if the file name doesn't exist). Did I close the file too early? Can you explain what went wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;

public class File
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println ("Welcome to the Weekly Sales Goal Program!");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int sales_goal;
        System.out.print ("\nPlease enter your sales goal (in dollars): ");
        sales_goal = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("\nPlease enter the input file name: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(fileName);

        double sum = 0.0;

        if (file.exists())
        {
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                double number = inputFile.nextDouble();
                sum += sales_goal;
            }

            inputFile.close();

            System.out.printf ("\nYour total sales for this week is: $", sum);

            if (sum >= sales_goal)
            {
                System.out.println ("\nYou reached your goal!");
            }
            else if (sum < sales_goal)
            {
                System.out.println("\nYou did not reach your goal :(");
            }

            System.out.println ("Goodbye!");
        }

    else if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input file name. Please try again.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't name your class File -- name it something else.  Like MyFile that way it won't conflict with java.io.File

Comment: use `String fileName =keyboard.next();`

Comment: I actually had MyFile I must have typed it wrong thanks though! Also I have to use keboard.nextLine() not keyboard.next()

Answer (score 3):

There is still a carriage return/line ffed in the stdin stream after the call to `nextInt` and the `nextLine` calls

```
sales_goal = keyboard.nextInt(); 
//...
String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
```

This is causing the `nextLine` to return immediately (cause it found the carriage return/line feed)

Add another call to `nextLine` after the `nextInt` call

```
sales_goal = keyboard.nextInt(); 
keyboard.nextLine(); // Consume carriage return
//...
String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: You can also simply trim the file name

Comment: Yes and no, what if the file name has spaces...;)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you fill the answer you seek by printing the path that `File` represents. Also, you can eliminate your first `if` test and I suggest you use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
keyboard.nextLine(); // <-- to get rid of the lingering \n from nextInt();
String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
File file = new File(fileName.trim());
if (!file.exists()) {
    System.out.printf("File %s Not Found%n",file.getPath());
    System.exit(1);
}
double sum = 0.0;
try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);) {
    while (inputFile.hasNextDouble()) {
        sum += inputFile.nextDouble();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I actually just needed to call to nextLine, but thanks for the response! The program is now working, I also fixed some other little errors.